# How to DROP a table inside while loop of SELECT in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I have a table where I store all the machine details, I need to delete all data and drop all tables of a specific user.

I'm trying to **DROP tables** based on the result from Select query, but it's not working as it is inside WHILE of SELECT query. Kindly help me with this.

```
 $sql="SELECT M_ID FROM machine_details WHERE Username='".$inname."'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 { 
   $delmid=$row['M_ID'];
   $delsta=$delmid."_status";
   $delpar=$delmid."_parameter";
   $sql1="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $delpar, $delsta";
   if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql1))
    {
       echo "Error in drop".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
   else
    {  
       $sql2="DELETE FROM machine_details WHERE M_ID=".$delmid;
       if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))
       {
           echo "Error in machine delete".mysqli_error($conn);
       }
     }
```

I'm not getting any errors from PHP or MariaDB, but the code doesn't **DROP** the table(It exists in phpmyadmin).

Any alternate or more efficient methods are also welcome.

**UPDATE :** ***The above code works perfectly fine now, kindly see the edit logs for better understanding about the issue I faced.***

Comment: why do you have a table for each user?

Comment: `DROP TABLE 'tablename'` is invalid. Lose the quotes...

Comment: It'll be cumbersome to manage all the data in a single table. These tables "xyz.parameters" will receive upto 500 inserts per day and "xyz.status" will receive around 50 inserts per day.      Imagine if I have 50 users and all data in a single table.

Comment: @marekful I tried, but still it doesn't work. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: cumbersome for who, the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID is int type! Dont place it in quotes. Right method is:

```
$sql2="DELETE FROM machine_details WHERE M_ID=".$delmid;
```

Comment: Never realised this until now. Thank you @Sorian !

Answer (score 1):

Try with Following Code to Delete.

For Delete you can use this code.

```
 <?php
    //delete.php
    include("connection.php");
    if(isset($_POST["_id"]))
    {
     $query = "DELETE FROM app WHERE _id = '".$_POST["_id"]."'";
     if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))
     {
      echo 'Data Deleted';
     }
    }
    ?>
```

- Note: Don't Delete any user data from the table, because if you need any history or detail report you can use this, for this you can put one flag.

Comment: Point Noted...Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the backquotes(`)
With its use M_ID is being converted to String type. Which should not happen... Because the primary key is int in your case

DELETE FROM machine_details WHERE M_ID=".$delmid;